# How could I get table name from OID in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I tried to use function get_rel_name(OID) to get table name, but the output is NULL, could anyone tell me why and how can I get the table name in backend of postgresql? thanks.

```
for (rti = 1; rti < root->simple_rel_array_size; rti++)
{
    RelOptInfo *rel = root->simple_rel_array[rti];
    printf("rel->relid=%d %s \n",rel->relid, get_rel_name(rel->relid));
}
```

In  src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c  in the function below.

```
void 
cost_seqscan(Path *path, PlannerInfo *root,
         RelOptInfo *baserel, ParamPathInfo *param_info)
```

Comment: In what context are you calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it should be

```
for (rti = 1; rti < root->simple_rel_array_size; rti++)
{
    RangeTblEntry *rte=root->simple_rte_array[rti];
    printf("table name is %s \n",get_rel_name(rte->relid));
}
```